# Odoo - How can we show multi level records

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

I want to show multi level records in odoo . Like if we have relation like

```
1-customer have many products and each product have a category
```

I can easily show products against a customer in odoo but what if i want to show products.category while i am standing in customer page.

```
customer fields ......
<field name="product.category" />
```

I can do like this ?

Comment: I think you're looking to use `related` fields, but I'm not understanding what/where you're trying to do. Can you include a screenshot or two of the areas you're wanting to see this?

Comment: You can take many2many compute field in customer screen that will take all categories from the products which is selected in customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the product category inside the Many2many tree view you can try something like this:

```
<field name='arch' type='xml>
  <form string='Customer'>
    <field name='product_ids'>

      <!-- Tree view shown in the form -->
      <tree name='Product Tree View'>
        <field name='name'/>
        <field name='category_id'/>
      </tree>
    </field>
  </form>
</field>
```